# Why the line is not showing up?/Processing

Tags: java, processing

tried different solutions but not working. anyone might help?
I want lines drawn from the center of the center circle and center of the outer circles.

```
void drawTree(float x, float y, float scale, float bulbs, float radius) {
  for (float i = 0.0; i<TWO_PI; i+=TWO_PI/bulbs) {
    fill(#13430C);
    noStroke();
    circle(x+cos(i)*scale, y+sin(i)*scale, radius);
    line(x, y, x+cos(i)*scale, y+sin(i)*scale);
  }
    
  fill(#5D4A07);
  noStroke();
  circle(x, y, radius);
}
```

Calling method:

```
void draw(){  
  drawTree(width/2, height/2, 60, 5, 50);

}
```

Comment: Have you checked if there might be a dependency between `noStroke()` and `line()`?

Comment: Yes. There was actually and I solved it by the adding new properties for the line(). Rookie mistake :((